# Java Properties saving over the internet

Tags: java, url, properties, web, fileoutputstream

I am trying to load and store properties to a properties file over a website (http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/). My goal is to edit a property in-game, and then save the new property.

Here is storing code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/config.properties");
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(url.getFile()), null);
```

The problem is that when I run this, nothing happens. Instead, it saves it it the C:/ drive. When I use prop.load(url.openSream());, it works. How do you use FileOutputStream to save the file over the internet.

If I can't get it to work over the internet, how can I save it in a jar?

Comment: ... A website isn't a filesystem. You could FTP/etc, store in a database, etc. You likely don't want to rewrite a jar; config files should be external. What's your actual goal?

Comment: @DaveNewton My goal is to have the project I am working on online. To do that, I either have to put the config file in the jar, or put it with the website.

Comment: I guess you understand the diff. between, "save the file over the internet." and "save the file on to some server via internet."

Comment: @Coupon22 and then everyone could change it as they would like, affecting everyone else? This doesn't seem to be good...

Comment: IMO you should take a step back first, you may be misunderstanding some fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you use `FileOutputStream` to save the file over the internet.

You don't, unless you've mounted a file system over the internet, which you can do but probably isn't what you're actually doing.

To send data to the server, in the usual case you talk to some server process that's been designed to do that (HTTP, FTP, SSH, etc.).

In your case, for instance, you might have a servlet container running as an HTTP server, and so use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or similar to `POST` data to a servlet, which would in turn update the config file. This also gives you a server-side opportunity to enforce security, which is important, as everything sent from a client is suspect until proven otherwise.